# Find the less frequent number in a NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have the following NumPy array:

```py
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
```

How can I find the less frequent number in this array?

Comment: try this `a.min()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`collections.Counter`](https://www.guru99.com/python-counter-collections-example.html)-

```
from collections import Counter
a = Counter([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
print(a.most_common()[-1][0])
```

Comment: Isn't 3 the least frequent number but this returns 0?  Am I missing something?

Comment: the bincount start at 0, so as there are no 0 in my list it returns 0

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1,2,3,1,2,1,1,1,3,2,2,1])
b = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
c = b[0][np.argmin(b[1], axis=0)]

print(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def least_frequent(array : np.array):
    dictionary = {}
    for value in array:
        if value in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[value] = dictionary[value] + 1
        else:
            dictionary[value] = 0
    least = -1
    least_key = -1
    for key in dictionary.keys():
        if least > dictionary[key]:
            least = dictionary[key]
            least_key = key
    return key
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using numpy:

```
cnt = np.bincount(a)
np.nonzero(cnt==cnt[np.nonzero(cnt)].min())[0][0]
```

output:

```
3
```